# How to count active users daily, weekly and monthly per month Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am currently trying to count how many distinct users are active:
At least once a day
At least once a week
At least once a month

per month, for every month in the year.

Ideally the output will be like this chart that is attached

[image]
What I have done so far is following this instructions "13. User login frequency" (https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions).

This example is not what I am looking  for because this calculates an average in all the months of the year and I need to calculate per month how many users are active at least once a day, how many users are active at least once a week and how many users are active ar least once a month.

Thank you very much

Comment: could you please provide both sample input and output in order to better understand what your scenario looks like?

Comment: The image uploaded may convey a wrong visualization as users active at least once a month will be a superset of users active at least for a smaller period during same month.  Better to use separate bars for every legend

Comment: There seems more errors with your desired views...
let's see for May 20- there are 3 users who were active at least once a month whereas there were 7 users who were active at least once each day in the same month; which is not possible

Comment: Please also clarify what is meant by 'users active at least once a week', because a week may overlap two month (begin in one and end in next)